# Failed to retrieve data with axios get from a date (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I need to retrieve data based on a date. I tested my route with Postman and everything works fine. However, when I do my axios query with a date, it returns an empty array. I understood that it would be a date format problem with axios, but I couldn't solve it. Could you help me please?

Here is my code in the front:

```
const getDailyWorking =()=>{
    let datas={
        activity_creationTimestamp: ('2022-06-28'),
        user_id:1
    }

    console.log(datas)
    return axios.get(config.api_url+'/dailyWork', datas).then((response)=>{
        console.log(response.data)
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err)
    })
}
```

Comment: you are making get request instead of post. (2nd argument of `axios.get` method takes axios config not data)

Comment: You are returning and ignoring `console.log(response.data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong type of request. A **GET** request can't include a body in the request, while a **POST** request can include a body in the request. Maybe you should check the documentation again and get the parameters sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the **GET** parameters like this `axios.get('/path', { params: datas }` which is equivalent to `axios.get('/path?activity_creationTimestamp=2022-06-28&user_id=1')`
. Otherwise, provide more information about the server side route.